# ZF2 Skeleton app Routing - children routes

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get working Routing in my app based on Zend skeleton application.

I need following mapping:

**localhost/**                             => Aplication/Controller/IndexController  => indexAction()  --> **this only works**
**localhost/portfolio/section**            => Application/Controller/PortfolioController  => indexAction()
**localhost/portfolio/section/action/id**  => Application/Controller/PortfolioController  => specifi_cactionAction()

I have this (module.config.php):

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'portfolio' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '[/portfolio/:section[/:action][/:id]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'section' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'  => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'      => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Portfolio',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index'     => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        'Application\Controller\Portfolio' => 'Application\Controller\PortfolioController',
    ),
),
```

Now, if I go to **localhost/portfolio/graphics/** I get error:
A 404 error occurred
PAGE NOT FOUND.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
No Exception available

I also tried in child route (without the / on start):

```
'route' => '[portfolio/:section[/:action][/:id]]',
```

I don't get it. Why this does not work?

Comment: Your route definition doesn't include a trailing slash - does `localhost/portfolio/graphics` work?

Comment: and you should be using `[portfolio/:section[/:action][/:id]]` since it's a child of your homepage route. Generally I avoid adding children to the homepage route - although it seems logical, in practice it seems to complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I tried both. But not at once  (such a dork). You saved me probably a lot of time! Thank you.